# YouTube API Android auto start

Tags: android, youtube-api

I use YouTube API in my app. My problem is, the video does not auto play, and the user has to press the play button to start playing.

My code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.playerview_demo);
((YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtube_view)).initialize(DEV_KEY, this);
```

`youtube_view` layout:

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView 
    android:id="@id/youtube_view" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

How do I make the video start automatically?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

What you are looking for is the Youtube API's [loadVideo method](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#loadVideo(java.lang.String)). From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#loadVideo(java.lang.String)):

> `public abstract void loadVideo (String videoId)`
>
> Loads and plays the specified video.

You can use it like this:

```
@Override
 public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
    boolean wasRestored) {
  this.player = player;
  player.loadVideo(video.id); // where video.id is a String of a Youtube video ID
}
```

In a similar vein, there is also the `cueVideo` method, which adds the video to the playlist, but does not automatically start playing the video.

Comment: I need cueVideo method +1 for that

Answer (score 5):

Using **loadVideo** function.

```
public abstract void loadVideo (String videoId, int timeMillis)
```

Loads and plays the specified video. Playback will start at the specified time in the video.

videoId - The ID of the video to be played
timeMillis - The time in milliseconds

FYR: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#loadVideo(java.lang.String)[reader](http://note.taable.com)

Comment: Only solution that worked for me  - the others don't start the autoplay on YouTube API v3

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `player.cueVideo("video_id");`

This will load the video, but it will not start auto playing. The video is auto playing because you're using `player.loadVideo("video_id");`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have solve this myself, then i post here:

```
 public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider paramProvider, YouTubePlayer  paramYouTubePlayer, boolean paramBoolean)
 {if (!paramBoolean)paramYouTubePlayer.loadVideo(CLIP_LINK);}
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation clearly states...

> Note: YouTube only counts playbacks that are initiated through the
>   native play button.

but u could simply call `youtubeplayer.loadVideo(VIDEO_ID,0) // 0 millis, start right away`

Otherwise you could use CHROMELESS controls and add custom controls to it. Then it may work. All the best..

Answer (score 0):

Check that `autoplay` feature is set to `1`. Player will load initial video in `autoplay` by default.

Please refer [Youtube Autoplay parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autoplay) for more.

Comment: This apply to AS, HTML5 but not Android.