# Auto play you tube video in YouTubePlayerView in Activity

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api, autoplay

I loaded my YouTube video using YouTubePlayerView in my activity. Once loaded i want to press *Play* button to play the video.

I want to auto play then YouTube video, is any possibilities to auto play the video in android activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube Api android autostart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354621/youtube-api-android-autostart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
loadVideo(youtube_id);
```

this will buffer the video and autoplay it, also make sure you won't have any view to overlay the YoutubeMediaPlayer because it will stop

Comment: Great :) Glad it does

Comment: If this solved your issue you should mark this answer with the green checkmark